# Stripe does not accept my token

Tags: python, jquery, django, stripe-payments

I am trying to create a django shopping site. But I can't get stripe to work. I don't belive it is anything workng in my code. It works fine withe the "tok_visa" sendt with javascript. But it does not accept my token. I have even tried manuelly writing it in.

views.py

```
if form.is_valid():
        token = form.cleaned_data['token']
        try:
            stripe.Charge.create(
                amount = 20000,
                currency = "nok",
                description = ""+form.cleaned_data['etternavn']+", "+form.cleaned_data['fornavn'],
                source = token,
                )
            form.save()
            return HttpResponse("<p>"+form.cleaned_data['fornavn']+"</p>")

        except stripe.CardError as e:
            form.add_error("Kortet ble ikke akseptert  "+token)
```

Jquery

```
Stripe.setPublishableKey('pk_test_H1PZQA7ypCa8UIlEy6S9ovhE');

$( '#payment-form' ).submit(function(e){
  $form = $(this);

  $form.find('button').prop('disabled', true);

  Stripe.card.createToken($form, function(status, response){
  if(response.error){
    $form.find('.payment-errors').text(response.error.message);
    $form.find('button').prop('disabled', false);
  }
  else{
    var token = response.id;

    $form.find('input[id="id_token"]').val(token);
    $('#id_token').val(token);
    $form.get(0).submit();
  }
  });
  return false;
});
```

Thank you for the help

Comment: What error are you getting?  And why are you doing both of `$form.find('input[id="id_token"]').val(token);` and `$('#id_token').val(token);`?

Comment: The error says that I am not using a test card. But I used a the card 424242424242

Comment: If the error says you're not, then you're likely not so I'd give it another try with the test card.  If you still get an error please provide the complete, exact error object you're receiving.

Comment: Used wrong card